# Windows 7 DHCP Client won't start

Tags: windows-7, windows, dhcp

The DHCP server on my Windows 7 machine refuses to start, when I click start in the services control panel I get:

"Error 2: The system cannot find the file specified."

The 'Path to executable' is 'C:\Windows\system32\svchost.exe -k LocalServiceNetworkRestricted'